# A function to find the n-th root of a number

Tags: c

While making a math application I required to calculate the n-th root of a number which is know to be a perfect n-th power. But in order to find the n-th root of that I used the following code

```
int i, j, set;
for (i = 1; i <= number; i++)
{
    j = pow(i, exponent);
    if (j == number)
    {
        set == i;
        return set;
    }
}
```

Inside a function Root(int number,int exponent).

Now to get the answer I need to capture the value of 'i' the moment 'j == number' takes place and I need to return this value of 'i' as a return value so that I can use it. 
It works but for certain values like 25,100,etc it gives garbage values as answer. What should be a correct coding for this programm ?

Comment: A [mcve], please.

Comment: More code needed. Consider posting minimal yet complete code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`j = round(pow(i, e))` would be a lot more stable; truncating floating point to the next-lower integer exaggerates tiny errors if they happen to be in the wrong direction.

But you can probably do better by estimating the root with an inverse exponent:

```
int root = round(pow(number, 1.0/e));
```

Then just check if `root` to the power of `e` is `number`.

Answer (score 3):

This is because `set` is uninitialized, ie, you never set it. You do this:

```
set==i;
return set;
```

which is comparing `set` to `i` (which does nothing). Then you return it uninitialized. Do

```
return i;
```

Since you don't use `set` for anything anyway.

Comment: Using directly "return i" also gives an unpredictable value

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo

```
set == i
```

probablye should be

```
set = i
```

DO NOT IGNORE COMPILER WARNINGS, and if you don't have them activate them. Also, try to use the most recent compiler, to get the newest diagnostic power.

Answer (score 0):

The function pow takes a `double` argument for the power, which would be `1.0 / n` for the n-th root.

This program then uses integer arithmetic on values bracketing the result, to see if they power up correctly. There is no need for an exhaustive loop.

The program run-arguments are `number` and `n-th root`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

unsigned powN (unsigned num, unsigned power)
{
    unsigned prod = 1;
    while (power) {
        if (power & 1)
            prod *= num;
        num *= num;
        power >>= 1;
    }
    return prod;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned number, root, answer, test;

    if(argc < 3) {
        return 0;
    }
    if(sscanf(argv[1], "%u", &number) != 1) {
        return 0;
    }
    if(sscanf(argv[2], "%u", &root) != 1) {
        return 0;
    }

    answer = (unsigned)pow(number, 1.0 / root);

    // check this value
    test = powN(answer, root);
    if(test == number) {
        printf("%u**%u = %u\n", answer, root, number);
        return 0;
    }

    // check the value above
    test = powN(answer+1, root);
    if(test == number) {
        printf("%u**%u = %u\n", answer+1, root, number);
        return 0;
    }

    // check the value below
    if (answer > 1) {
        test = powN(answer-1, root);
        if(test == number) {
            printf("The %u**%u = %u\n", answer-1, root, number);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    printf("No exact %u-th root of %u\n", root, number);
    return 0;
}
```

Sample runs:

```
test 49 2
7**2 = 49

test 50 4
No exact 4-th root of 50

test 64 3
4**3 = 64

test 16807 5
7**5 = 16807
```